# In data frame, choose column that is most variable from others

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with, for example, replicates from an experiment in different columns. If each row in my data frame is a sample, with columns a, b, c as replicates, I want to:

1. Determine the variation between the replicates (What is the difference between the highest and lowest values in each row)? Put this in a new column called "variation.")
2. If the variation is greater than 10, omit the one replicate that is furthest away.

How can I accomplish this in this data frame? I want new columns:
"max" - highest value of a, b, c for each row
"min" - lowest value of a, b, c for each row
"variation" - max/min for each row

Then, I want to omit the data points in a, b, or c that are furthest away from the others so the remaining points have <10 variation.

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 100, 20),
                 b = rnorm(10, 2000, 500),
                 c = rnorm(10, 50, 20))
df$max = apply(df, 1, max, na.rm = T)
df$min = apply(df, 1, min, na.rm = T)
df$variation = df$max/df$min
```

(Also, how can I calculate the max and min using dplyr and %>% notation?)

Comment: How do you define "furthest away"? In the example data frame that you give, how would you calculate determine which one was furthest away?

Comment: For instance, if the values in 1 row are 1, 2, and 100, then the min = 1, max = 100, variation = 100. I want to omit the 100, which would leave the other 2 points with <10-fold variation.

Comment: I guess this is an assignment, [learn to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115934/312631), show us what you tried. What is the output at the R console? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @PaulRougieux this is for working with my data, not a class. I do not know how to automatically choose which sample to eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using dplyr [pipes](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html#piping), with [mutate](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) and [group_by](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by). I reshaped the data in long format using tidyr [gather](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) and reshaped it in wide format at the end using [spread](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(100)
dtf_wide <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 100, 20),
                 b = rnorm(10, 2000, 500),
                 c = rnorm(10, 50, 20))
```

Reshape data in long format. Group by id (row number in the wide format) Then compute the variation and the distance from the median value.

```
dtf <- dtf_wide %>% 
    # Explicitely add an identification column (for the grouping)
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    # put data in tidy format, one observation per row
    gather(key, value, a:c) %>% 
    arrange(id) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(variation = max(value, na.rm = TRUE) / min(value, na.rm = TRUE),
           median = median(value),
           distancefrommedian = abs(value-median),
           maxdistancefrommedian = max(distancefrommedian)) 
head(dtf)

# # A tibble: 6 x 7
# # Groups:   id [2]
#      id   key      value variation    median distancefrommedian maxdistancefrommedian
#   <int> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>              <dbl>                 <dbl>
# 1     1     a   89.95615  49.58856  89.95615            0.00000              1954.987
# 2     1     b 2044.94307  49.58856  89.95615         1954.98692              1954.987
# 3     1     c   41.23820  49.58856  89.95615           48.71795              1954.987
# 4     2     a  102.63062  31.37407 102.63062            0.00000              1945.507
# 5     2     b 2048.13723  31.37407 102.63062         1945.50661              1945.507
# 6     2     c   65.28121  31.37407 102.63062           37.34941              1945.507
```

If varation is greater than 10, remove the line where the value is further away from the median (you could change that rule here to take away more lines if needed).

```
dtf <- dtf %>% 
    # For each id, 
    # Take all lines where variation is smaller than 10
    filter(variation <= 10 |
               # If varation is greater than 10,
               # Filter out lines were the value is further away from the median 
               (variation > 10 & distancefrommedian < maxdistancefrommedian)) %>% 
    # Keep only interesting variables
    select(id, key, value) %>% 
    # Compute the variations again (just to check)
    mutate(variation = max(value, na.rm = TRUE) / min(value, na.rm = TRUE)) 
head(dtf)
#      id   key     value variation
#   <int> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1     a  89.95615  2.181379
# 2     1     c  41.23820  2.181379
# 3     2     a 102.63062  1.572131
# 4     2     c  65.28121  1.572131
# 5     3     a  98.42166  1.781735
# 6     3     c  55.23923  1.781735
```

Reshape data to obtain a table in wide format similar to the original data frame.

```
dtf_wide2 <- dtf %>% 
    spread(key, value) 
head(dtf_wide2)
#      id variation         a        c
#   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1  4.385692  89.95615 41.23820
# 2     2  4.385692 102.63062 65.28121
# 3     3  4.385692  98.42166 55.23923
# 4     4  4.385692 117.73570 65.46809
# 5     5  4.385692 102.33943 33.71242
# 6     6  4.385692 106.37260 41.23099
```

Comment: This is great! Almost correct, except that I need to re-group by ID in the second chunk, correct?

Comment: Oh yes, I removed the `ungroup()`, it is not needed. I updated the output of `head(dtf)`.